# Android CheckBox text not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I'm trying to dynamically create some CheckBoxes in one of my Android activities, but it's not rendering the text.

Here is my simplified code...

1. Layout XML:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:padding="10dip">

       ...
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/register_attracted_to"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical" />
       ...
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Activity code:

   ```
   final LinearLayout attractedTo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.register_attracted_to);

   final CheckBox male = new CheckBox(this);
   male.setText("Male");
   attractedTo.addView(male);

   final CheckBox female = new CheckBox(this);
   female.setText("Female");
   attractedTo.addView(female);
   ```

My "real" code is a little more complex (any dynamic) than this, which is why I haven't simply included the checkboxes in the layout itself.  However, even dumbing down my code still doesn't render the checkbox text properly.

Here's a screenshot to demonstrate (see the "Attracted To" section), with a little extra to demonstrate that my vertical layout appears to be working properly otherwise:

[image: Android checkboxes missing text]

Comment: I wouldn't dynamically add UI components, because there is a difficulty reviewing them at development time. a developer needs to run the whole app just to see the added components. I humbly suggest adding them with visibility gone. It is very lightweight because they are never drawn but they can still be found (findViewById).

Comment: The checkboxes are generated via an HttpRequest, meaning that your suggestion is impossible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Of course I figure this out shortly after posting a bounty. ;)  It turns out that since I was setting my container view's background color to white, the default white text was blending in.  The solution was to set the text color of each checkbox.  i.e.:

```
final LinearLayout attractedTo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.register_attracted_to);

final CheckBox male = new CheckBox(this);
male.setText("Male");
male.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.foreground_text));
attractedTo.addView(male);

final CheckBox female = new CheckBox(this);
female.setText("Female");
female.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.foreground_text));
attractedTo.addView(female);
```

Comment: this too happened to me. It seems like the default text color for checkboxes is white on pre-honeycomb devices

Comment: yea, just like the text views

Answer (score 5):

you are not setting the Layout parameters, Layout parameter says how the control will be shown

```
final CheckBox female = new CheckBox(this);
female.setText("Female");
female .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
attractedTo.addView(female);
```

Comment: I tried doing this previously, which did not work for me: `male.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`  I'll try your solution though as soon as I get a moment.

Comment: It looks like checkbox only accepts `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, and there is no third parameter for this constructor, as you supply here.  I tried the two-parameter constructor using `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` for each, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Not for me.  I toyed with it all weekend to no avail, both in my emulator and on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's due to the simplification of your real code, but did you set width and height of your checkbox ?

Comment: See my comments in [@jazz's response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689475/android-checkbox-text-not-displaying/7689533#7689533).

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same and found that I was using `setText("")` in the `initialisation code` rather than `setChecked(false)`. Dur!