# More than one checkbox in listview row

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Basically what I am trying to do is to have 4 checkboxes inside each row of the listview. Because I am retrieving the information from the webservice, I need to set text to the checkbox. I tried using textview and it managed to work. Therefore it means that there is something wrong with my coding of the checkbox. Can anyone please tell me where have I gone wrong? Thanks.

This is the code I have written for the baseadapter but this code will result to force close.

```
public class BaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private static ArrayList<Result> searchArrayList;
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public BaseAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Result> result) {
  searchArrayList = result;
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return searchArrayList.size();
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return searchArrayList.get(position);
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ViewHolder holder;
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();

   holder.txtQn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
   holder.txtC1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice1);
   holder.txtC2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice2);
   holder.txtC3 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice3);
   holder.txtC4 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice4);


   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  holder.txtQn.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getQuestion());
  holder.txtC1.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getChoice1());
  holder.txtC2.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getChoice2());
  holder.txtC3.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getChoice3());
  holder.txtC4.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getChoice4());

  return convertView;
 }

 static class ViewHolder {
  TextView txtQn;
  CheckBox txtC1;
  CheckBox txtC2;
  CheckBox txtC3;
  CheckBox txtC4;
 }
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible things:
1) Check that your `searchArrayList.get(position).getChoice1()`, and so on are not just empty string "" but have real texts.

2) Make sure your check box text has [different color other than the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689475/android-checkbox-text-not-displaying).

Comment: Thanks! Managed to solve it somehow. And also thanks for the reminder(: