# chechbox not displaying text in gridview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display dynamic Checkbox in grid view but it not showing the text. It only highlight the text when I check/uncheck it.
I know my question is same like [Android CheckBox text not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689475/android-checkbox-text-not-displaying). But I didn't find the way to solve it.

Here is my code.

Activity Code:

```
try {
    JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result3);// result3 is response from
                                            // server
    JSONObject json = null;
    final String[] str3 = new String[JA.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
        json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
        str3[i] = json.getString("name");
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, str3);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    gridView.setAdapter(adp3);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}
```

Layout XML:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        ></GridView>
```

Comment: How are you creating dynamic check box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass the ArrayAdapter if you want to use it to display anything other than a simple TextView.

You can then initialize the View in the GetView() method of your custom Adapter.

Here's an example of a basic subclassing of ArrayAdapter.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int resourceId;
    private List<String> data;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<String> data)
    {
        super(context, resourceId, data);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (view == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(resourceId, null);
        String data_item = (String) ((ListView) parent).getItemAtPosition(position);
        CheckBox checkBox = ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box));
        // Do your thing
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?