# Custom listView on android, two colors on same item

Tags: android, listview

I want to customize android listView. I need an icon at right side, header with green color and larger font and sub header with black color and smaller font and again another icon at the left. It should look like following:

[image]

Following is my code:

```
Class MyList extends Activity{
ListView listView ;
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String iconUrl = "http://www.someurl.com/icon.png";
String iconUrl2= "http://www.someurl.com/icon2.png";
int counter = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
someFunctionOnButtonClicked();

//following function to add items to list dynamically
public void someFunctionOnButtonClicked(){
String string1 = "List item "+counter+" Header";
String string2 = "List item "+counter+" sub-header";
listItems.add(string1+"\n"+string2);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now how can I set different font-weight and color for two headers on same list item? How can I include images on both end? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Create a custom ArrayAdapter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19858682/2947592

Comment: You should be able to do all of that in the XML for the row layout.

Comment: Is it? how? Can you please show me some example. @Jim

Comment: You will also need a custom ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom Adapter for the list by extendsing the ArrayAdapter class.
This is an excellent tutrial [Adapter implementations - vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own custom ArrayAdapter for this, and set the text color programmatically inside the getView method. Have a look at [this example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example).