# Android Custom Checkbox/RadioButton Text Not Displaying

Tags: android, android-checkbox, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I'm trying to create custom RadioButtons/Checkboxes programmatically with info from a Http request (creating a survey in-app). I've tried the suggested solutions in [Android Checkbox text not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689475/android-checkbox-text-not-displaying) but the text still isn't appearing.

I'm able to create the custom button views, but for some reason the text doesn't display. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

checkbox_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/multiselected" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/multiunselected" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

radio_selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/singleselected" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/singleunselected" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

Here's how I'm creating them:

```
if (mQuestion != null && mQuestion.isSingleResponse()
                    && mAnswerTitles.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mAnswerTitles.size(); i++) {
                    Answer answer1 = mAnswerTitles.get(i);
                    RadioButton answer = new RadioButton(getActivity());

                    answer.setText(answer1.getTitle().toString());
                    answer.setTextSize(24);
                    answer.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    answer.setId(answer1.getId());
                    answer.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radio_selector);
                    answer.setLayoutParams(mRadioGroupAnswers.getLayoutParams());
                    answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mNextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                    mRadioGroupAnswers.addView(answer);
                }
            } else {
                if (mAnswerTitles != null && mAnswerTitles.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mAnswerTitles.size(); i++) {
                        Answer answer1 = mAnswerTitles.get(i);
                        CheckBox answer = new CheckBox(getActivity());
                        answer.setText(answer1.getTitle().toString());
                        answer.setTextSize(24);
                        answer.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        answer.setId(answer1.getId());
                        answer.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_selector);
                        answer.setLayoutParams(mRadioGroupAnswers.getLayoutParams());
                        answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                mNextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                        if (mAnswerHolder != null) {
                            mAnswerHolder.addView(answer);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And the group/layout I'm adding them to:

```
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/answerGroup"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/answerTextHolder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
```

It looks like the text is actually just getting hidden by the image - rather than being put on the image and re-sizing the image with the text length:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The trick was using setBackgroundResource instead of setButtonDrawable:

```
answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radio_selector);
```

[image]

Thought after doing some testing - I do advise also overriding the Radio/Checkbox button drawable as well if you're doing it completely custom.